# Copy array of objects into an another array is changing the order of elements

Tags: arrays, angular

[console.log values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk9ff.jpg)

I have an array of object coming from the server.

It's sorted properly by step_id.

When I push this object into another array, the new array is not sorted properly.

```
 this._stepService.getSteps()
        .subscribe(
            stepReturn => {

               console.log(stepReturn.json()); //obj sorted
               this._stepService.step.push(...stepReturn.json())
               console.log(this._stepService.step); //obj sorted differently
            }
```

Anyone has an idea what's wrong with it?

Additional info: The issue has started when the array had 11 objects.

[loop on array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLJ1S.jpg)

If I loop on my this._stepService.step and display the steps id. It is properly sorted. (see loop on array Link)

Comment: It might be that your step_id is being treated as a string rather than a number, so item 10/11 would sort before 2-9 since '10' < '2' with a string comparison.

Comment: It should'nt be sorted again when I copy the array into the other.

Comment: Could you include the console output in your question or, if too large, a representative sample?  Sorry, I see the link at the top of the question...

Comment: Can you see the image through the link console.log values?

Comment: Yes, I can. There must be some sort of properties attached to _stepService.step. It would be pushing the items in the correct order, so the collection that is receiving them must be ordered. Possibly, there is a getter on the 'step' property that provides an 'ordered' list.